# Attempting to use Jersey (JAX-RS) and Weld (CDI) in Tomcat 7. Getting noClassDefFoundError for javax.annotation.ManagedBean

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm trying to make Weld work with Jersey on Tomcat 7.0.34 but seem to be running into this issue. The actual exception is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/ManagedBean
```

but I'm not explicitly annotating anything with the @ManagedBean annotation, so I'm guessing that Weld implicitly does this. Should this annotation have been provided by Weld, or am I missing some other dependency?

My pom.xml file contains:

```xml
<dependency>
    <!-- CDI implementation -->
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${weld.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing anything, or is there a much greater problem with trying to use Weld and Jersey?

---

catalina.out when deploying my web app:

```
...
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.34/libexec/webapps/tracker.war
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900 1.1.10 (Final)
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat7.Tomcat7Container initialize
INFO: Tomcat 7 detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets and Filters. Injection into Listeners is not supported
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry <clinit>
WARNING: Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry <clinit>
WARNING: Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
...
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer initialize
INFO: CDI support is enabled
Jan 03, 2013 2:21:22 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.16 11/28/2012 02:09 PM'
```

catalina.out when making a HTTP request to the servlet using the @Inject annotation

```
Jan 03, 2013 2:23:12 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  substrate.tracker.api
Jan 03, 2013 2:23:12 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class substrate.tracker.api.ProjectsResource
  class substrate.tracker.api.UsersResource
  class substrate.tracker.api.IssuesResource
  class substrate.tracker.api.PingResource
Jan 03, 2013 2:23:12 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class substrate.tracker.api.exception.ParameterExceptionMapper
Jan 03, 2013 2:23:12 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer initialize
INFO: CDI support is enabled
Jan 03, 2013 2:23:12 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.16 11/28/2012 02:09 PM'
```

The servlet responded to the request with a 500 HTTP status code. The root cause stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/ManagedBean
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:116)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:103)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(IoCProviderFactory.java:89)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:153)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:251)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProviders(ProviderServices.java:148)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.ExceptionMapperFactory.init(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:74)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1307)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Strangely, the stack trace doesn't show in the catalina.out, instead, the log file shows what looks like the app being redeployed!

Comment: I've added more information to the original post.

Comment: Is this causing a problem, or it's just something in the logs? I'm unable to tell. I'm wondering if perhaps there's more to it and this is a symptom.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely causing a problem, I can't use CDI / @Inject as I get the exception mentioned above. I should try switching to another container, like glassfish to see if it happens with the provided APIs.

Comment: You could also try TomEE if you wanted to stay on tomcat.

Comment: I tried switching to TomEE but that introduced some problems of its own. That didn't seem to like Jersey either. I may try glass fish.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I solved it by dropping the current version of jersey which is 1.16 and using an older version which is 1.8. After using the older version, I no longer have this error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Going back to 1.11 stops this error from occuring, but the DI still doesn't appear to work (the object is null).

Comment: I should probably have also said that I'm not thrilled that seems to "fix" the problem with the exception. I'd rather understand the cause than simply drop several versions back. Did you ever find out exactly what caused this? Better yet, were you using tomcat + weld + jersey, or some other stack?

Comment: @Steven Bakhtiari yes I'm using tomcat 7 with weld. I also do not think there is a major difference between 1.8 and 1.16. I would prefer to use the slightly older version than spend a whole day trying to get the mix to work together.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, once I overrode the ServletContainer as stated at: 
[Weld + Jersey + Tomcat?](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Weld-Jersey-Tomcat-td5959010.html)

To be able to have it running, I annotated my jersey service class with @RequestScoped and then the injection worked.

Answer (score 0):

just look inside the jersey jar (i use jersey 1.14), specifically at the pom file.
You will see that it expects some provided dependencies, and one of them is javax.ejb 3.1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This jar contains the necessary class : javax.annotation.ManagedBean. If you import any other jar containing this class wont work. That is because the way the jersey jar was bundled, but that is another story.

Just add this dependency inside your pom and everything will work ok.

Nicu